# .NET / C# - Reflection - System.IO.File ever used

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Is there a way to use reflection to completely "scan" an assembly to see if System.IO.File or System.IO.Directory is ever used? These are just example classes. Just wondering if there is a way to do it via reflection (vs code analysis).

**update**:
see comments

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Tommy Carlier suggested, it's very easy to do with [Cecil](http://mono-project.com/Cecil).

```
using Mono.Cecil;

// ..

var assembly = AssemblyFactory.GetAssembly ("Foo.Bar.dll");
var module = assembly.MainModule;

bool references_file = module.TypeReferences.Contains ("System.IO.File");
```

Comment: I downloaded monocharge-20090414.tar.gz from the dailybuilds and do not see Mono.Cecil.dll. Is Mono.Cecil namespace in another assembly now?

Comment: It's in monocharge/1.0/Mono.Cecil.dll

Answer (score 3):

The fantastic NDepend tool will give you this sort of dependency information.

Load your dll in NDepend and either use the GUI to find what you want, or the following CQL query:

```
SELECT TYPES WHERE IsDirectlyUsing "System.IO.File"
```

and you should get a list of all the types that use this.

Comment: you can also have indirect dependencies like
SELECT TYPES WHERE IsUsing "System.IO.File"
and you'll get classes like A using B using C... using System.IO.File

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest looking at [Mono Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil) for this. With Cecil, you can enumerate all the classes, methods and even the IL-instructions (including all the methods calls).

Comment: I downloaded monocharge-20090414.tar.gz from the dailybuilds and do not see Mono.Cecil.dll. Is Mono.Cecil namespace in another assembly now?

Answer (score 1):

I don't remember where, but I found this handy piece of code:

http://gist.github.com/raw/104001/5ed01ea8a3bf7c8ad669d836de48209048d02b96/MethodBaseRocks.cs

It adds an extension method to `MethodInfo`/`ConstructorInfo` that parses the `ILByteArray` into `Instruction` objects.

So with this, you could loop over every `MethodInfo`/`ConstructorInfo` in the assembly, then loop over every `Instruction` on that `MethodInfo`/`ConstructorInfo`, and check if any of those `Instruction` objects contains an `Operand` which is an instance of a `MemberInfo` which has a `DeclaringType` that is equal to either class.

Comment: I think it comes from http://evain.net/blog/articles/2009/04/30/reflection-based-cil-reader

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of dependent assemblies via `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies()`.  I don't believe you can comprehend namespace usage via reflection.  Try looking at System.CodeDom.  That may help you parse the code.

Comment: Well I'm not so interested that System.IO was used but that the class System.IO.File was used.

Comment: I don't think just because an answer is probably wrong is justification for giving it a negative score. I upvoted to bring this to 0.

Answer (score 0):

[.NET Reflector](http://reflector.red-gate.com/Download.aspx) can do this, or something close to it. The other day I checked to see where a particular type was used.

ReSharper might also help. I do this with my own symbols all the time - I suppose it would also work for .NET Framework types.